# How to adjust margin for axis label from hclust dendogram plot

Tags: r, plot

I have the following code:

```
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
plot(hc)
plot(hc, hang = 0.5, sub="", xlab ="")
```

Which produce the following plot:

[image]

As described in the image above. How can I `push`  they *Height* label further right?

Comment: See `?mtext()` and and change le `line` argument

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the `mgp` argument to `par`:

```
par(mgp=c(2, 1, 0))
plot(hc, hang = 0.5, sub="", xlab ="")
```

[image]

```
par(mgp=c(1, 1, 0))
plot(hc, hang = 0.5, sub="", xlab ="")
```

[image]

The other two arguments control the tick marks and the scale position so for instance:

```
par(mgp=c(2, 3, 2))
plot(hc, hang = 0.5, sub="", xlab ="")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A workaround might be to remove the ylab and just add it as text at appropriate  coordinates, like this:

```
plot(hc, hang = 0.5, sub="", xlab ="", ylab = "")
text(0, -50, "Height", srt = 90)
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the use of `mtext` could help

```
plot(hc, hang = 0.5, sub="", xlab ="", ylab = "")
mtext(text = "test", side = 2, line = 2)
```

yielding this plot

[image]

`side = 2` defines the lefthand side, and `line` indicates the "excentricity". You can play around some more with the `line` and `adj` parameters (and more) like this:

```
plot(hc, hang = 0.5, sub="", xlab ="", ylab = "")
mtext(text = "t2", side = 2, line = 2, col = "blue")
mtext(text = "t1", side = 2, line = 1, col = "blue")
mtext(text = "t0", side = 2, line = 0, col = "blue")
mtext(text = "tlow", side = 2, line = 0, col = "blue", adj = 0)
```

yielding the following plot

[image]